# Update a module at the end of a webpack compilation, before emit

Tags: webpack

I’m working on a [webpack loader/plugin combination](https://github.com/smyte/jsxstyle-loader). The loader extracts static styles from JS files, writes a (virtual) CSS file with those styles, and then adds a `require` at the top of the JS file that points to the virtual CSS file. The plugin supplies the virtual filesystem (the very excellent `memory-fs`).

Up until now, I’ve been writing one CSS file for each JS file, but I’d like to write one file for each *compilation* instead. This means that I’ll need an aggregation step at the end of the compilation.

What I’m currently doing is a bit of a hack, to say the least:

- Before compilation, write a virtual CSS file with a specially formatted path and prepend it (prefixed by a special loader) to the `entry` array. The special loader ignores input content and instead returns the aggregated styles.
- Aggregate styles as each JS file is processed by the loader.
- Force an extra compilation with `need-additional-pass`.

Problem is that the recompilation triggered by `need-additional-pass` takes twice as long (at least in production).

I’m going to try some kind of child compiler nonsense in a bit, but in the mean time, I figured I’d ask SO to see if anyone’s had experience with something like this.

**In summary**, is it possible to recompile a single required module before emit? To be clear, I don’t want to emit the CSS file. I want to treat this extracted CSS file as a file that’s being required so that the user can decide what to do with it.

Additional questions:

1. Can I recompile a module with a child compiler and have it updated in the parent compiler?
2. Am I going about this the wrong way?

I’m using latest webpack (3.5.5).